# "grunt-contrib-concat" not found

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt for a few hours now, without success, and I hope you can help me.

- I use osx 10.10
- npm installed and updated
- grunt installed
- sample gruntfile.js created from different docus
- first package installed

  - `npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev`

My gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

      // Project configuration.
      grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
          dist: {
            src: 'html/javascripts/*.js',
            dest: 'html/javascripts/plugins.combined.js'
          },
        },
      });

      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

      // Default task.
      grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

    };
```

I have a sample HTML project where I added the gruntfile.js and tried to run the grunt command. But I get errors everytime.

> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed? Warning: Task "concat" not found. Use --force to
>   continue.

But it is installed with grunt in the ./node_modules/ folder. I can run grunt so the folder seems to be ok but I can not run it without errors.

I hope someone here can help me, because I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: Try this **require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);** in the init of the file. Remember install **"load-grunt-tasks"**.

Comment: @JesúsQuintana i installed load-grunt-tasks and add the line before and after the line where i register the task but no change, same error.

Comment: Remove the **grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');**, load-grunt-task will read your package.json dependencies, devdependencies, etc, to detect all grunt packages and load automatically, and execute **grunt concat:dist** must work